# incompatible Parquet schema for column "ex: x is of type String" Column type: STRING, Parquet schema

Tags: hive, impala

I have an existing External Table called for example YYYYYY that contains n number of columns and this table is loaded daily with partitioned column as extract_date.

We got a request from business to add few more columns in the existing table. To implement this we have done following things.

```
DROP existing partitions from Hive

alter table xxxx.yyyyyy add columns (
     `c10` string COMMENT '',
     `b` string COMMENT '',
     `c11` string COMMENT '',
     `c12` string COMMENT '',
     `c13` string COMMENT '',
     `c14` string COMMENT '',
     `c15` string COMMENT '') CASCADE;

alter table xxxx.yyyyyyy change `c8` `c8` string COMMENT '' after `c7` CASCADE;
```

After I did the above 2 steps, I went to Hive and did `MSCK REPAIR TABLE xxxx.yyyyyy;`

Partitions added (there are partitions from 2018) along with my new fields.

Before the changes I was able to query the data both from Impala and Hive, but after executing `ALTER` commands, I am getting the error as below.

```
> select * from xxxx.yyyyyyy where extract_date like '2019%';
Query: select * from XXXXX.YYYYYYY where extract_date like '2019%'
Query submitted at: 2020-05-09 11:57:10 (Coordinator: ' xxxx.yyyyyyy .c9'. Column type: STRING, Parquet schema:
optional fixed_len_byte_array a_auth [i:12 d:1 r:0]
```

Whereas in Hive I am able to browse the data with no issues. So I have an issue only in Impala.

Troubleshooting steps:

Created new table without additional columns and pointed the external path as new and copied the previously created partitions to new path.

`MSCK REPAIR TABLE TABLE NAME;`

Both in Impala and Hive a `select` query is working.

2. Added additional fields to the newly created table with ALTER commands then did the following things

`MSCK REPAIR TABLE TABLE NAME;`

In Impala : 
`REFRESH TABLE TABLE NAME;`
`INVALIDATE METADATA TABLE NAME;`

This time in Hive select query worked but in Impala got the above mentioned error.

Can some one guide me why this is happening and how to fix this issue.

Impala Shell v2.12.0-cdh5.16.2

Comment: What was the intent of using `after c7` in the `alter table xxxx.yyyyyyy change c8 c8 string COMMENT '' after c7 CASCADE;` ?

Comment: New columns which i added those will be att he end of the all table columns. That is the PCI column as per our schema definition that column should be after c7

Comment: Can u please help me on this.

Comment: Can you update your post with output from `describe extended xxxx.yyyyyy`?